# Is there some simple word/phrase instead of "render"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

English is not my native tongue, so it's actually hard to explain the problem here. It seems like in my language it's hard to explain "render" in a single word. So I need some alternatives for the following example:

> User processes, in opposite, do not "trust" themselves. This is why a "true" spinlock, which **renders** a process as uninterruptible for an infinite time, is not provided for user processes. At most, OS provides hybrid version of a spinlock and a mutex: during the short period of time the process, which tries to grab a spinlock, is actually **rendered** as uninterruptible. But if the time expires until the process acquires the spinlock, the process is moved to the waiting state, allowing other processes to be run on the same core. So "fairness" is provided.

My current candidates are:

1. Make (it become something)
2. Turn (it into some state)
3. Is considered as (something)

are these correct? Or what's a better solution?

Comment: Unless you provide more context, it is impossible to recommend a word that fits it.

Comment: @CinCout: Hi, nice to see you again. But isn't the current context enough?

Comment: it's of the form `render A as B` which `B` is a state.

Comment: Don't think so. Render can actually have various meanings, so unless I am sure of its meaning in the current context, it is tough to recommend an alternative.

Comment: @CinCout OK, I'll try to edit it. Done.

Comment: *"it's of the form render A as B which B is a state"*: should "interpret" fit?

Comment: FYI: The English in this snippet isn't very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "make" for "rendered" in this case ("make it become something", as you said).  A spinlock can "make a process uninterruptible".  The verb "to render" is more formal, which is why you are seeing it in this documentation.

Comment: Can I say the word render is of advanced level? It has so many meanings...

Comment: @user7813604 The word "make" has even more meanings!  The best description is that "render" is more formal.  It is used in documentation and contracts.